# how can i code an addon to read firefox bookmarks

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, bookmarks, add-on

I'm familiar with basic FF addon development and have created a "test" toolbar button. Now when I click on this button I want my addon to read FF bookmarks. As simple as that.

Now I've spent 3 days. Have read uncountable tutorials, forums and blogs. Have gone through official FF addon development tutorials, but its a big mess. I'm not sure where to look for this info.

All I need is the API references of the methods/functions which can be called from inside an addon code to read FF bookmarks...

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/Bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox 3:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Places

Its not that hard.  The hardest part is probably finding out where the sql lite database is located on users computer.